# Problem doing multiplication operation in a select between a float and an integer in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, select, multiplication, operation

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hMKF.png)
Hi, I have this problem when I do this operation between a float and an integer number.

```
select codventa, cantidad, precio, cantidad * precio from 
ventas v, detallesventas dv
where v.codventa = 23 and dv.codventa = v.codventa
```

Instead of 399,96 the result is 396. I don't know why

Comment: I did 
select 4*99,99  and it give me this [link](https://imgur.com/a/YLE78Zw) so I think the problem is that decimal separator of my regional settings is the "," character

Comment: I think it will be better if you edit your Question to include the table definition. Kindly also include the record in text, not in an image. Any information should be in your Question, not in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite uses `.`, not `,` for the decimal point in a floating pointer number (Do *any* sql databases accept a comma for it?).

When you multiply a number (`4`) by a string (`'99,99'`) the leading numeric portion of the string is converted to a number, so you're seeing the result of `4 * 99`. (`SELECT typeof(precio) FROM yourtable` will be `text`, not `real`).

`SELECT 4*99,99` returns two columns - one `4*99`, one `99`, because comma is the column/value separator.

Some useful reading:

- More about [datatypes in sqlite3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) including rules for conversion between types.
- [Syntax of numeric literals](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#literal_values_constants_) in sqlite3 (Which specifically mentions that it always uses period and never comma).