# How to read float values with decimal comma using read_sql_query

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting problems using `DataFrame.read_sql_query` and SQLite on my german computer: according to the local settings for numbers, the decimal character is a comma ',' and not a dot '.'

Working with CSV and pandas, it is easy to set the decimal character to ',' in the functions `read_csv` and `to_csv` using the decimal parameter.

But I am missing this parameter in the sql functions `read_sql` / `read_sql_query`. When I read a float values from my SQL table, pandas is getting back objects instead of a floats.

Example:
This is my table in SQLite.

```
CREATE TABLE myvalues (
p_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
time INTEGER NOT NULL,
y FLOAT NOT NULL);
```

I use sqlite3 and pandas to read the values in 'y':

```
dns_sqlite = r'db\dm.output.sqlite3'
conn_sqlite = sqlite3.connect(dns_sqlite)
df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from myvalues, conn_sqlite)
```

The head of the DataFrame is then:

```
p_id        time                    y
0   61      1575272655947000000     0,299893262748943
1   60      1575272655947000000     0,325854761161171
2   57      1575272655947000000     0,323828854628018
3   62      1575272655947000000     0,310302948951226
4   58      1575272655947000000     0,32878052447951
```

and the dtypes are:

```
p_id     int64
time     int64
y       object
dtype: object
```

where you can see that `y` is of type 'object' instead of 'float'.

I don't understand where the problem is coming from. It is because of pandas, which is not using the local settings of my computer? Or is the sqlite3 module responsible?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually I just do a test using only python sqlite to read the table myvalues and again the float values are fetched as string. So the problem seems to come from sqlite3. Is there may be a possibility to tell sqlite3 to use ',' instead of '.'?

Answer (score 0):

I my have found the root cause of my problem:
An equivalent question was posted and answered in stack overflow:
[Problem doing multiplication operation in a select between a float and an integer in sqlite [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62225393/problem-doing-multiplication-operation-in-a-select-between-a-float-and-an-intege/62225862#62225862)

So I suppose I should either use '.' instead of ',' when I import my data into SQLite.

Or I could replace the ',' by a '.' after I import my data into SQLite using:

```
update myvalues
set y = replace(y, ',', '.')
where y = '%,%';
```

Which is not nice but I currently don't see any cleaner solution.